# is there a way of keeping all obs condtion on top_n value from another column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rscript, top-n

i need to find a way using tidyverse to keep all obs. but filtering all other observation than the top_n values from a column.

example:

```
Name| title      | rank
John| xxxxxx     | 1
John| yyyyyyy    | 1
John| zzzzzz     | 1
max | xxxxxx     | 3
max | yyyyyyy    | 3
max | zzzzzz     | 3
evan| xxxxxx     | 2 
evan| yyyyyyy    | 2
evan| zzzzzz     | 2
```

then i would like to keep top_n rank = 2, and still keep all observation of that rank so not only unqiue rows

so it would look like this

```
Name| title      | value
John| xxxxxx     | 100
John| yyyyyyy    | 100
John| zzzzzz     | 100
evan| xxxxxx     | 200 
evan| yyyyyyy    | 200
evan| zzzzzz     | 200
```

is this possible in dplyr / with tidyverse?

Comment: I do not really understand your question. Where is this 'value' coming from?

Comment: + in above comment, I would like to add why don't you filter `rank <3`?

Comment: I think AnilGoyal‘s comment is the solution to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the rank beforehand (e.g. your data looks like the below) you could `nest` on the groups, use `slice_min`, and then `unnest`. But nesting and unnesting can get slow on large data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~Name, ~title, ~value,
  "John", "xxxxxx", 100,
  "John", "yyyyyyy", 100,
  "John", "zzzzzz", 100,
  "max", "xxxxxx", 300,
  "max", "yyyyyyy", 300,
  "max", "zzzzzz", 300,
  "evan", "xxxxxx", 200,
  "evan", "yyyyyyy", 200,
  "evan", "zzzzzz", 200
)

df %>% 
  nest(data = c(title)) %>% 
  slice_min(order_by = value, with_ties = TRUE, n = 2) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(data))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   Name  value title  
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr>  
#> 1 John    100 xxxxxx 
#> 2 John    100 yyyyyyy
#> 3 John    100 zzzzzz 
#> 4 evan    200 xxxxxx 
#> 5 evan    200 yyyyyyy
#> 6 evan    200 zzzzzz
```

If your data really is as simple as this, then AnilGoyal's solution is the best:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~Name, ~title, ~rank,
  "John", "xxxxxx", 1,
  "John", "yyyyyyy", 1,
  "John", "zzzzzz", 1,
  "max", "xxxxxx", 3,
  "max", "yyyyyyy", 3,
  "max", "zzzzzz", 3,
  "evan", "xxxxxx", 2,
  "evan", "yyyyyyy", 2,
  "evan", "zzzzzz", 2
)

df %>% filter(rank < 3)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   Name  title    rank
#>   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 John  xxxxxx      1
#> 2 John  yyyyyyy     1
#> 3 John  zzzzzz      1
#> 4 evan  xxxxxx      2
#> 5 evan  yyyyyyy     2
#> 6 evan  zzzzzz      2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>